# Run the 'CouchbaseLiteSwift' pod lib on mac os?

Tags: ios, macos, couchbase-lite

Was anyone able to run the 'CouchbaseLiteSwift' pod lib on mac os? I am getting:

building for Mac Catalyst, but linking in dylib built for iOS Simulator, file '.../Pods/CouchbaseLite-Swift/iOS/CouchbaseLiteSwift.framework/CouchbaseLiteSwift' for architecture x86_64

I also found no application that runs CouchbaseLite on macOS except: https://github.com/couchbaselabs/CouchbaseLiteViewer that uses objC libraries.

Comment: Couchbase Lite does not support Catalyst as yet. You will have to use the mac version of the library for your mac apps

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue by using Cocoapod. But you can do it another way.

First [download](https://www.couchbase.com/downloads) Couchbase Lite

Then, unzip the file and drag CouchbaseLiteSwift.framework from your Finder to the Xcode navigator.

Click on Project > General > Embedded Binary and add CouchbaseLiteSwift.framework to this section.

Import the framework and start using it in your project.